# When is persistence.xml necessary for Play 2.1.1 Java? Entities don't persist in a many-to-one relationship

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1, persistence.xml

In my program, I have a Task model with a `allDates` field, which is a collection of all the Dates that task occurs on. My goal is to make a calendar manager that allows users to input tasks that repeat on certain days.

In Tasks, I defined a OneToMany relation between a task and its dates in [line 34](https://github.com/six5532one/calpractice2/blob/repeatingEvents/app/models/Task.java). To treat the elements of `allDates` as an entity, I wrapped each date in a DateHelper model that is another Ebean entity.

Right before I save the Task, my console output indicates someTask.allDates.size() is accurate and a number greater than one. After I save the task, however:

1) I query DateHelpers in [line 194](https://github.com/six5532one/calpractice2/blob/repeatingEvents/app/models/Task.java) for all DateHelper instances for a given task, and the server only returns the first DateHelper that was added to someTask.allDates, rather than returning the same number of DateHelpers that was added to the task before I saved.

2) someTask.allDates.size() also returns 1, and the only element in allDates is the first DateHelper I added before saving the task.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257284/play-framework-jpa-how-to-implement-one-to-many-relationship) and [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaJPA) that Play developers should modify a persistence.xml file to integrate with JPA. Do I need to do this if I am importing ebean? Also, my program successfully maps one User to many Tasks, so I am confused about why the OneToMany mapping does not work for one Task to many TaskHelpers.